# URL in anchor tag is not working

Tags: html

I want to link one HTML page to another one. So, I use anchor tag

```
<a href="xyz.html>sign</a>.
```

As my "xyz.html" is in the current folder and on click on "sign", it does not work.

Even I also applied jQuery on click method.

Comment: First, please paste some code here. You definitely don't need to use JavaScript for this. What goes wrong when you click the link? Is it trying to load the file from the wrong directory?

Comment: Just delete this question quickly while not so that many ppl have seen it, Mrs Front-end Developer.

Comment: Close double quote

Comment: `<a  href="xyz.html">` sign</a> close your `"  "`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "sign" is in your anchor tag, try this :

```
<a href="xyz.html">Sign</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You not Close the `double quote`

```html
<a  href="xyz.html">sign</a>
```

The`<a>`  tag defines a `hyperlink`, which is used to link from one page to another